# What happens if your partner hits you in Pegs and Jokers?

Tags: pegs-and-jokers

Question for marble movement.

Your partner has a marble in their in-spot (start of home). If you hit that marble with yours, what happens to your partners marble? And yours?

We have been playing with this sequence of events:

- The rule is that when you hit your partners marble it is sent to its in-spot.
- That position is now occupied by your marble so now your partners marble hits yours and sends you to your in-spot.
- The end result would be both of you are in your in-spots.

Any thoughts on this play?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is actually (*and strangely*) correct.

https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/72993/instruction-sheet

> *Rule 3:*
>
> - **If a player lands on a hole occupied by a teammate's ("your partner's") pegs, the teammate’s peg is moved to the hole directly in front of his/her home position ("the in-spot").**
> - If *your partner's* home position hole ("in-spot") is occupied by one of his/her own pegs then move that peg to his/her start position ("start area").
> - **If *your partner's* home position hole ("in-spot") is occupied by any other peg, follow rules 3 and 4 recursively until the last peg has found an unoccupied hole.**

> *Rule 4:*
>
> - If a player lands on a hole occupied by an opponent’s peg, the opponent’s peg is returned to the opponent’s start position.

Some of the basic rules:

> - You cannot pass or land on your own marble (*either moving forward or moving backward*).
> - You can pass or land on your partner's or an opponent's marble.
> - If you lands on your partner's marble, your partner's marble is moved to its in-spot
>   (*the space just outside of the safe/home area*).
>   **If your partner's in-spot is occupied by one of your marbles, that marble is moved to its in-spot and then the landed on marble is moved to your partner's now empty in-spot.**
>   If your partner's in-spot is occupied by any other marble, that marble is returned to its starting position (*"start area"*).
> - If you lands on an opponent's marble, the opponent's marble is returned to its starting position (*"start area"*).

Other links:

https://liftbridgefurniture.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Lift-Bridge-Furniture-How-to-Play-Pegs-and-Jokers.pdf

http://www.rovin.texasgoodsam.com/Games/Jokers%20&%20Marbles%20Game%20Rules.pdf